# C++ Logic error: Instruction does not load data

Tags: c++, algorithm

[COMPILER ONLINE TEST:www.onlinegdb.com](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler#)

**Update 14 Dez:FIND ERROR DONT SOLVE**

> for(az=0;az<=strlen(str);az++);  //<strlen OR <=strlen

**Objetive output= ditado6:' CEM VINTE TRES REAIS E ONZE CENTAVOS'**

```
bool insere_caracter(const char *digito[],int indice){
   voz.ditado[voz.posicao]=' '; //espaço inicial
   unsigned int az;
   char str[33];
   strcpy(str,digito[indice]);   //CHANGE FOR BELOW
      //for(az=0;az<strlen(str);az++   
      for(az=0;az<=strlen(str);az++){
        voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]= digito[indice][az];
      }//for az
   return true;
}
```

---

This code aims to decipher a number in expression (voice) of money.

Have error in code, dont have any warnings.
Please guide why and how to avoid this consequence.

According to brief inspection, the fault of the code is in the function "decoder_cardinal"

[RUN CODE HERE: Compiler online CODECHEF](https://www.codechef.com/ide)

**Output: have here the error**

```
Inteiro:123 
Fracionario:11 
ditado1:' CEM VINTE TRES REAIS' 
posicao 00:20 
ditado2:' CEM VINTE TRES REAIS E ' 
posicao 01:23 
posicao 02:28 
ditado3:' CEM VINTE TRES REAIS E ONZE' 
posicao 05:36 
ditado6:' CEM VINTE TRES REAIS E ONZE' //HERE DONT INSERT WORD "CENTAVOS"
posicao 06:36
```

**Output after Disable line 228:** //decoder_cardinal(voz.centavos);

```
Inteiro:123 
Fracionario:11 
ditado1:' CEM VINTE TRES REAIS' 
posicao 00:20 
ditado2:' CEM VINTE TRES REAIS E ' 
posicao 01:23 
posicao 02:23 
ditado3:' CEM VINTE TRES REAIS E ' 
posicao 05:31 
ditado6:' CEM VINTE TRES REAIS E CENTAVOS' //HERE good write CENTAVOS;
posicao 06:31
```

**Output correct is** (enable line 228)

```
Inteiro:123 
Fracionario:11 
ditado1:' CEM VINTE TRES REAIS' 
posicao 00:20 
ditado2:' CEM VINTE TRES REAIS E ' 
posicao 01:23 
posicao 02:28 
ditado3:' CEM VINTE TRES REAIS E ONZE' 
posicao 05:36 
ditado6:' CEM VINTE TRES REAIS E ONZE CENTAVOS' //Completed
posicao 06:36
```

**CODE COMPLETE**
#ifndef *TVP_AUDIO*
#define *TVP_AUDIO*

```
    #define SIZE_DITADO  256
    #include <stdio.h> 
    #include <string.h>
    #include <iostream>    
    //#include <array> 

    const char *romanos[] = {"HUM", "DOIS", "TRES", "QUATRO", 
     "CINCO", "SEIS", "SETE", "OITO", "NOVE", "DEZ", "ONZE", 
     "DOZE", "TREZE","CATORZE","QUINZE","DEZESSEIS",
     "DEZESSETE","DEZOITO","DEZENOVE","VINTE","TRINTA",
     "QUARENTA","CINQUENTA","SESSENTA","SETENTA","OITENTA",
     "NOVENTA","CEM","DUZENTOS","TREZENTOS","QUATROCENTOS",
     "QUINHENTOS","SEISCENTOS","SETECENTOS","OITOCENTOS",
     "NOVECENTOS","MIL","DOIS MIL","TRES MIL","QUATRO MIL",
     "CINCO MIL","SEIS MIL","SETE MIL","OITO MIL","NOVE MIL",
     "DEZ MIL","ONZE MIL","DOZE MIL","TREZE MIL",
     "CATORZE MIL","QUINZE MIL","DEZESSEIS MIL",
     "DEZESSETE MIL","DEZOITO MIL","DEZENOVE MIL"};
     const int arabicos[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
     12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,200,300,
     400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,
     8000,9000,10000,11000,12000,13000,14000,15000,16000,17000,
     18000,19000};
     const char vozes[][20] = 
     {"UM","HUM","DOIS","TRES","QUATRO","CINCO","SEIS","SETE",
     "OITO","NOVE","DEZ","ONZE","DOZE","TREZE","CATORZE",
     "QUINZE", "DEZESSEIS","DESESSETE","DEZOITO","DEZENOVE",
     "VINTE","TRINTA","QUARENTA","CINQUENTA","SESSENTA",
     "SETENTA","OITENTA","NOVENTA","CEM","DUZENTOS",                                                  
     "TREZENTOS","QUATROCENTOS","QUINHENTOS","SEISCENTOS",
     "SETECENTOS","OITOCENTOS","NOVECENTOS","MIL","E","REAIS",
     "CENTAVOS","ZERO","TANCAINFO","VERIFICADOR"};

     struct precifica{
        unsigned int reais;
        unsigned int centavos;
        unsigned int tamanho;
        unsigned int posicao;
        unsigned int c_size; //tamanho do array de cardinal
        unsigned int n_size; //tamanho do array de numeros
        unsigned int v_size; //tamanho do array de vozes
        int index[SIZE_DITADO/4];
        char ditado[SIZE_DITADO];
      }voz;

    bool decoder_preco(char alvo[]);
    void zerar();
    bool insere_caracter(const char *digito[],int indice);
    void decoder_cardinal(int numero);
    void find_word(std::string str);
    void splitstr(std::string str, std::string deli);
    void size_array();
    void insere_centavos();
    void monta_voz();

    bool decoder_preco(char alvo[]){

         unsigned int pos1=0, pos2=0;
         bool part1=false;
         bool part2=false;  
         char p1[]={' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','\0'};
         char p2[]={' ',' ',' ',' ','\0'};

         for(int az=0;az<=strlen(alvo);az++){
  
            if(part1==true && part2==false){  
                if(isdigit(alvo[az]))p1[pos1++]=alvo[az];
            }
            if(part1==true && part2==true){  
                 if(isdigit(alvo[az]))p2[pos2++]=alvo[az]; 
            }
      
          if(alvo[az]=='$' && alvo[az+1]!=' ')part1=true; 
          if(alvo[az]==' ' && alvo[az+1]!=' ')part1=true; 
          if(alvo[az]==',' || alvo[az]=='.')part2=true;  
         }//for

         if(part1 == false && part2 == false)return false;
         if(pos1 ==  0 && pos2 == 0)return false;
         unsigned int inteira=0, fracionaria=0;
         //sscanf(myarray, "%d", &i);
         sscanf(p1, "%d", &inteira);
         sscanf(p2, "%d", &fracionaria);

         voz.reais=inteira;  
         voz.centavos=fracionaria;  

        return true;
       }//fim decoder_preco

      void zerar(){

           voz.ditado[voz.posicao]=' ';
           voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='Z';
           voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='E';
           voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='R';
           voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='O';
           voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]=' ';  
       }

       bool insere_caracter(const char *digito[],int indice){

             voz.ditado[voz.posicao]=' ';  
             unsigned int az;
             char str[33];
             //printf("digito[%d]=%s \n",indice, digito[indice]);
             strcpy(str,digito[indice]);

             //printf("strlen:%d \n",strlen(str));
             for(az=0;az<=strlen(str);az++){
                voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]= digito[indice][az];
                char caracter=voz.ditado[az];
             }//for az
          return true;
       }
       void decoder_cardinal(int numero){

           if(numero == 0){
           zerar();
           return;           
           }
           // acha a quantidade de elementos no array
         int indice = (sizeof(arabicos) / sizeof(arabicos[0]))-1;
         while (numero > 0) {
              if (numero >= arabicos[indice]) {
          
                insere_caracter(romanos,indice); 
                numero -= arabicos[indice];
               } else {
                        indice--;
                      }
         }//while
       }

    void find_word(std::string str){

      std::string s1;
      for (int i = 0 ; i < voz.v_size; i++)
      {
         s1=vozes[i];
         if (s1.compare(str) == 0)
            {
             voz.index[voz.posicao++]=i; 
             break;
             }
       }//for
    }

    void splitstr(std::string str, std::string deli = " ")
    {
      voz.posicao=0;
      memset(&voz.index,-1,sizeof(voz.index)); 

      std::string res; 
      int start = 0;
      int fim = str.find(deli);
        while (fim != -1){
          res=str.substr(start, fim - start);
          find_word(res);
          start = fim + deli.size();
          fim = str.find(deli, start);
        }//while
       res=str.substr(start, fim - start);
       find_word(res);
    }

    void size_array(){

        int len1 = *(&romanos + 1) - romanos;
        int len2 = *(&arabicos + 1) - arabicos;
        int len3 = *(&vozes + 1) - vozes;
        voz.v_size=len3; 
        if(len1 == len2){
           voz.c_size=len1;
           voz.n_size=len2;
         }
         else printf("VERIFIQUE OS ARRAYS DE DECODIFICACAO");

    }

    void insere_centavos(){
         voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]=' ';
         voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='C';
         voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='E';
         voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='N';
         voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='T';
         voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='A';
         voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='V';
         voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='O';
         voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='S';
    }

    void monta_voz(){

       size_array();
       memset(&voz.ditado,'\0',sizeof(voz.ditado)); 
       voz.posicao=0;
       decoder_cardinal(voz.reais);
       printf("Inteiro:%d \n",voz.reais);
       printf("Fracionario:%d \n",voz.centavos);
       voz.ditado[voz.posicao]=' ';
       voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='R';
       voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='E';
       voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='A';
       voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='I';
       voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='S';
       printf("ditado1:'%s' \n", voz.ditado);
       printf("posicao 00:%d \n", voz.posicao);
       if(voz.centavos != 0){
          voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]=' ';
          voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='E';
          voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]=' ';
          printf("ditado2:'%s' \n", voz.ditado);
          printf("posicao 01:%d \n", voz.posicao);
          decoder_cardinal(voz.centavos);
          printf("posicao 02:%d \n", voz.posicao);
          //insere_centavos();
          printf("ditado3:'%s' \n", voz.ditado);
          voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]=' ';
          voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='C';
          voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='E';
          voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='N';
          voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='T';
          voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='A';
          voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='V';
          voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='O';
          voz.ditado[++voz.posicao]='S';
          printf("posicao 05:%d \n", voz.posicao);
          printf("ditado6:'%s' \n", voz.ditado);
          printf("posicao 06:%d \n", voz.posicao);

        }else{
        //se for zero centavos
        }

      std::string s = voz.ditado;
      splitstr(s, " "); //separa em palavras
     }//monta_voz

     int main(){
         char alvo[]="R$123,11";
         decoder_preco(alvo);
         monta_voz();
     }
     #endif
```

Comment: Please extract a [mcve], and include that, along with expected and actual output in your question. There's way too much code there, at the moment. Please also run the code to an automatic formatter (built into most IDEs). This will make the structure more obvious, overall making it easier to read and understand, which in turn makes it easier to catch errors.

Comment: Debugger.  Please edit your question with the results of your debugging session.  This looks like an excellent opportunity to advance your debugging skills.